# who am I? (official politically correct)

Tags: meaning

what is the name for a person who does things for a wealthy person such as pay bills take care of investments and insure things are in order for that person on a day to day basis

Comment: Financial arrangements, or legal as well? Household management? It will make a difference in the answer.

Comment: Maybe it's a "Personal Assistant" but if you were rich enough to have a personal assistant you'd likely have a separate "Investment Advisor/Financial Planner" for those specific activities.

Answer (score 1):

You are an 'aide':

> aide (eɪd) n.
>    1.  an assistant or helper, esp. a confidential one.

[aide. (n.d.) Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary. (2010). Retrieved November 13 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aide]